# Python vk_api. Как поймать события выхода человека из беседы и кикнуть его?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пользуюсь **VkLongPoll из vk_api.longpool**
Авторизация с помощью токена в сообществе

```py
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk)

def main_loop(self) -> None:
        for event in self.longpoll.listen():
            # Как то сделать проверку на выход из беседы
            # И потом кикать через removeChatUser как я понял
```

Как поймать это событие и кикнуть того, кто вышел из беседы?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, информацию о боте. Меня смущает то, что Вы используете `vk_api.longpoll` вместо `vk_api.bot_longpoll`. Очень сомневаюсь, что Вы смогли бы получить ключ пользователя с необходимыми правами. Какой тип авторизации Вы используете? Вы можете дополнить свой вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Дополнил в вопросе

Comment: Какую версию `Python` Вы используете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала стоит сказать, что Вы используете неправильный модуль. Вам нужен `vk_api.bot_longpoll`.

Отследить выход человека из беседы можно, проверяя сообщение на наличие ключа `action` с типом `chat_kick_user`.

***Пример (`Python 3.8+`):***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


ACCESS_TOKEN = ''  # Подставьте свой!
GROUP_ID =         # Подставьте свой!


vk_session = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, GROUP_ID)


def main():
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and (action := event.obj['message'].get('action')):
            if action['type'] == 'chat_kick_user':
                vk.messages.removeChatUser(
                    chat_id=event.chat_id,
                    user_id=action['member_id'],
                )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Не забудьте, что боту необходимо выдать права администратора беседы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В event.obj нет ключа message и он мне выдает ошибку
Вот весь event.obj:
{'date': 1587406150, 'from_id': 474106968, 'id': 5028, 'out': 0, 'peer_id': 474106968, 'text': 'D', 'conversation_message_id': 30, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'random_id': 0, 'attachments': [], 'is_hidden': False}

Comment: @Hahan't Какую версию `Long Poll API` Вы используете? Я проверял на `5.103`. Изменить версию можно на одноимённой вкладке в настройках сообщества.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало)